# SSRS - Multiple font or color within a chart item

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using Report Builder 3.0. Long story short, I want to make the font bold for the text in the red box that you see in the image below:

[image]

Basically, it's just one expression in the legend field of my value, however, for clarity's sake (for my end users) I wish to make the "title part" bold. I found the following solution for textboxes in a tablix using Html by checking off the "HTML – Interpret HTML tags as styles." checkbox within the Textbox's properties. (http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/10/31/using-different-formats-within-a-single-textbox-in-ssrs.html)

However, I can't find anything similar for graphs! I mean if MS thought about it for tables, I presume they must've given it some thought for a chart setting too.

Thanks to all!

p.s. As an aesthetic solution to my problem, I did think of simply creating a new title field, moving it to the exact same location and formating it. But I'm surious whether there'd be some more "proper" way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same approach for one of my charts.

**STEPS**.

Select the Chart series to open property pane. In my case, the `chart series` name is `TWR Chart Series`

[image]

Select the **color** property and select to build the `expression`.

I'm posting one of my expression. You can build your own expression base don your field names etc.

```
=IIF(Fields!ProductID.Value = 1 OR Fields!ProductID.Value = 6,"#00425E",   

IIF(Fields!ProductID.Value = 3 ,"#6B8797",

IIF(Fields!ProductID.Value = 5 OR Fields!ProductID.Value = 7,"#799179",

IIF(Fields!ProductID.Value = 4 AND Fields!sort.Value=99,"#6bb1be","#48597B"))))
```

If used sensibly, you should get your desired results.Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, however in my case this would not work since my "fake titles" in the legend are simply text that I included prior to my field names. In other words, my personalized legend field looks as so: ="Taux (général)" & Fields!Blabla.Value & Fields!Haha.Value & etc. So based on ur suggestion, how could i indicate in the color's parameter that when this text string appears in the legend to change its font? I don't know whether you have any suggstions, if not thanks for input regardless!